# Bit Operators: Difference between << and <<= or >> and >>= in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Please explain to me in detail the difference between << and <<= and as well as >> and >>=.
I know how shift operators work, but I am not so sure about them when it comes to >>= or <<=.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know what I was thinking when I was trying to get it and posted this stupid question.
:)

Comment: StackOverflow exists for asking questions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `<<` only shifts left. `<<=` shifts left *and* assigns.

`<<=` is to `<<` what `+=` is to `+`.

#### EDIT

As suggested by MByD, here is an example

```
int x = 1;

/* Print 32. */
printf("%d\n", x << 5);

/* x stays the same. */
printf("%d\n", x);

x <<= 5;

/* x has become 32. */
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: @cnicutar - you get there before me every time  today :) (another +1) an example will be even better :)

Answer (score 3):

In C, and many other languages, you can put `=` after an operator as a shortcut. Instead of writing...

```
x = x + 5
```

...I can write...

```
x += 5
```

These are called [compound assignment operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators). You're just seeing the versions of these for bit shift operations.

```
x >>= 1
```

...is the same as...

```
x = x >> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

<< can be used on both variables and constants.

```
5 << 2; // this is ok.
a << 2; // this is ok too.
```

<<= will change the lvalue, so that:

```
a <<= 2; // bit-shifts a by two positions.
5 <<= 2; // wrong, 5 is 5 and will always be 5.
```